# Bug on read csv format , assertin the header in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So i have a tiny issue that i think is associated to my computer configs.
Everytime i read_csv doesnt matter the dataset. The headers they come out in this specific format.

```
Index(['BotId;UserId;StorageDate;StorageDateBR;StorageDateDayBR;Date;Time;Hour;Category;Action;MessageId;Extras;Steps;LastState;CampaignSource;ChosenProduct;TypeofProduct;PostalCode;CPF;City;Original_UserId;Original_BotId'], dtype='object').
```

Even tho they are perfectly divided in the dataset itself, i think the issue is correlated to the handling of saving csv files in my pc.
If u guys know any ways to quickly fix this without interacting through all the headers and positioning their head to their columns unto their according order i would appreciate it. And the reason behind it i would appreciate the quick fix

```
df = pd.read_csv('Exemplo_processamento.csv',on_bad_lines='skip')
```

Comment: It's not clear from your description exactly what the problem is, but I would guess you need to pass in `;` as the `sep` (separator) parameter when you read the csv

Comment: it did thank you so much